# Argument for the zero vector not being defined as an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, education

Two days ago, my lecturer of Advanced Numerical Methods gave a review on the topic about eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Just as the lecturer presented the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, a student asked the lecturer why the zero vector does not count as being an eigenvector of a square matrix. Then the lecturer replied along the line of:

> The zero vector is, by definition, not an eigenvector because otherwise $\vec{A}\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$ is true for any $\vec{A} \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$.

For some reason, I was not satisfied with that argument. In fact, I think the argument is sloppy, if not downright fallacious. However, being an engineer with no formal background in logic, I cannot disprove it. On the other hand, that reasoning was given by a professionally trained mathematician, so who am I to argue otherwise?

If I were to explain to someone else about the reason for the zero vector not being defined as an eigenvector, I would have said, based on my understanding of the problem of finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors, the following:

> We would like to find a unique $\lambda$ such that the homogeneous system $(\lambda\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{A})\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ has non-trivial solution. In other words, $\lambda\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{A}$ has a non-trivial nullspace, restricting $\lambda\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{A}$ to be singular. If $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ were allowed to be a solution, then, by the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofLinearAlgebra.html), it had to be the *only* solution, i.e.  $\lambda\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{A}$ had to be non-singular, contradicting our goal.

That is, the reasoning contains tangible cause-and-effect arguments. I would have also proceeded to show briefly how $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ is a useless eigenvector when it comes to solving linear systems of ordinary differential equations, the bread and butter of science and engineering.

So the question is, is the argument given by the lecturer valid? Is it an answer commonly given by mathematics educators to such question? If it is, please enlighten me.

Comment: I think that what the lecturer is enough: if the vector zero is allowed, then **any** scalar would be an eigenvalue, since for a linear map $\;T\;$ we have $\;T\vec 0=\vec 0= k\cdot\vec 0\implies k\in\Bbb F\;$ , for any scalar $\;k\;$ , is an eigenvalue. We don't want that to happen for several reasons.

Comment: @Timbuc I see your point but the lecturer's argument was, if the zero vector is allowed, then $\vec{A}\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}$ is true for **any** (square) matrix over $\mathbb{F}$ , which is semantically different from your argument.

Comment: Is there any situation involving eigenvectors, where having the 0 among the eigenvectors would be usefull? In a base of eigenvectors it would be of no use.

Comment: @PYK No, not semantically but only in *form*: the meaning is the same, as (square or not)  matrices are linear maps.

Comment: @mvw When talking of eigenspaces it is very useful, as we take the span of eigenvectors corresponding to one particular eigenvalue and thus we *add* the zero vector. Still, it is only for the sake of having a linear *subspace*, as zero **still** isn't an eigenvector.

Comment: If you allowed 0 as an eigenvalue and went on in the diagonalization process, the resulting diagonal matrix with a 0 in the diagonal would not be similar to the original. And doing the decomposition would be a mess.

Comment: May I summarize all this in an answer, maybe as a Community Wiki, so that it has an answer? How does one do community Wikis, BTW?

Comment: @Timbuc By "semantically different" I did not mean the differences between coordinate-based and basis-free descriptions of the same argument. Let me put it this way: if the zero vector is allowed, then any matrix $\vec{A}$ would satisfy the eigenequation, since for a scalar $\lambda$ we have $\vec{A}\vec{0} = \vec{0} = \lambda \cdot \vec{0} \implies \vec{A} \in M_{n}(\mathbb{F})$, for any matrix, which satisfies the eigenequation. This argument elicits a "so what?" response. It definitely qualifies to be a  [non sequitur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)).

Comment: The "so what" question elicited shows the asker *still* hasn't studied enough to fully understand the mess that'd involve, then the lecturer could simply remark "wait a little, then you'll find out why that isn't a derivable situation". I've no idea what you mean is a non-sequiitur? The elicited argument, the lecturer explanation, what I wrote...?

Comment: @Timbuc Let me clear things up a bit. Your argument using eigenvalues is fine. I proceeded to reformulate the lecturer's reasoning in terms of the form of your argument, in order to highlight the differences. The emphasized objects are different. Yes, the propositions used in both arguments may be reduced to an unambiguous, logical equivalence, but that does not necessarily implies that they are both equally effective, didactically.

Comment: @PYK Ok, I think now it perhaps is clearer to me what your point is, and my last comment stands: upon being asked "why the zero vector can't be, *by definition*, an eigenvalue?", I think the best and most educative thing to do is to remark that then every linear map/matrix/operator (1) would have that vector as an eigenvector, and (2) **any** scalar would be an eigenvalue corresponding to it. This already seems to point towards a major problem here: if *all* scalars can be eigenvalues, what's the point in defining them?  One can also say: wait until later, things will be clearer in a while.

Comment: @Timbuc Again, (2) is perfectly fine, but I wouldn't say the same to (1). For example, I don't see system matrices explicitly appear in the solutions to systems of differential equations, but eigenvalues and eigenvectors do appear explicitly, and hence I can directly relate the undesired consequences of allowing the zero vector to be an eigenvector. One may reach the same conclusion from (1), but possibly only through a huge detour of implications, for which I wouldn't care without a good reason. Perhaps that's about the differences in priorities mathematicians and engineers establish...